# How to create a void JQueryPromise in typescript?

Tags: jquery, interface, typescript, jquery-deferred

I'm having trouble understanding the type for a JQueryPromise.
I'd like my promise to be of type void, but while the interface definition accepts a void I don't know how to return/cast the promise to match the interface signature. When I compile I get the error:

*Call signatures of types '() => JQueryPromise<{}>' and '() => JQueryPromise' are incompatible.*

Here's a sample of the code:

```
module Sample {
    export interface Ifoo {
        bar: () => JQueryPromise<void>;
    }

    export class fooClass implements Ifoo {
        bar() {
            var result = $.Deferred();
            // logic
            return result.promise();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong; or what could I be doing right?

Thanks!

-John

Comment: Don't use `void` in promises. Every promise should represent a result *value*.

Comment: What do you `resolve()` the deferred with?

Comment: @Bergi `undefined` is allowed and is equivalent to `void` : http://promisesaplus.com/

Comment: @basarat: Of course it's allowed, but it's not *recommended*. I said "should", not "must" :-)

Comment: Its useful e.g when you need a timeout in a promise way. Don't use void if you want to return a value. I don't think there is any special recommendation :)

Comment: Bergi, I'm using void because I don't pass back a value. All I care about is if the deferred action succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `<void>` when creating the defferred:

```
module Sample {
    export interface Ifoo {
        bar: () => JQueryPromise<void>;
    }

    export class fooClass implements Ifoo {
        bar() {
            var result = $.Deferred<void>();
            // logic
            return result.promise();
        }
    }
}
```